# Headless setup of NixOS on raspberry pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, nix, nixos

Having followed [Zupo's](https://github.com/zupo/nix) execellent post which was mentioned in a [NixOs Weekly](https://weekly.nixos.org/2019/01-terranix-debian-packaging-elm2nix-raspberrypi-3.html), I wondered if it might be possible to setup a rasberry pi3 without the need for a monitor and use wifi rather than an ethernet cable.

There are all ready several blogs that set up [raspbian headlessly](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md) by the addition of an ssh file in the boot directory and wpa_supplicant.conf in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant` directory, but I am unsure how to achieve this in the NixOS way.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering this myself, too :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. How to install NixOS on raspberry or how to configure already installed one or setup wifi or something else.

Comment: @spinus basically set up NixOS on a  raspberrypi using wifi and without the use of a monitor or keyboard attached to the raspberrypi (headlessly).

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that if you don't have NixOS on raspberry already (aka reconfiguration of existing system). To install frash installation I think you need to install either from media (like USB) or just put flashcard into PC and write image into flash.